# Perform some action events on button click inside received email body

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am submitting a web form. After user submitting, I am sending an email to Admin for confirmation. There are three buttons in my email template "Approve", "Reject" and "More Clarification". My client requirement is to perform any click inside the email body with any redirection in our website. 
Is it possible to perform actions in email body itself without any redirection. Please find the attached email template which i am submitting for approval to admin.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Q1l.png)

Comment: You can't reliably put a form in an email, and you certainly can't execute JS. More info [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/forms/) and [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/#four)

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding your problem you will have to do following tasks:
1. Embed JavaScript function with the email that can fire ajax request.fire and forget style.
2. You need web service to handle the ajax request in your application.

This is my assumption. I have not jump into the coding.